# Issue with type parameter: "cannot select from parameterized type"

Tags: java, generics

I am facing an issue with generics.

Here is one of my classes that uses generics:

```
public class TokenServerResponse<D> {

    private String responseCode;
    private String responseMessage;
    private D responseData;
    ....
```

Here our class: `TokenServerResponse` is parameterized with `D`.

I would like to specify the type in one of our methods as follows:

```
   protected ResponseEntity<TokenServerResponse<DigestResponseData>> digest(long globalMerchantUId, String expirydate, String pan, boolean updateExpiryDate) throws Exception {
        DigestRequest digestRequest = new DigestRequest();
        digestRequest.setGlobalMerchantUid(globalMerchantUId);
        digestRequest.setExpiryDate(expirydate);
        digestRequest.setPan(pan);
        digestRequest.setUpdateExpiryDate(updateExpiryDate);
        return restTemplate.postForEntity("/digest", digestRequest, TokenServerResponse<DigestResponseData>.class);
    }
```

However, I get the following compiler error: `cannot select from parameterized type`.

How can I use the type parameter `D`? I have also tried casting to no avail. What am I getting wrong?

Here is how the `digest` method is called:

```
    ResponseEntity<TokenServerResponse<DigestResponseData>> digestResponseEntity = digest(823, "1505", pan, true);
```

Comment: you can't do TokenServerResponse<DigestResponseData>.class. Try TokenServerResponse.class

Comment: @MauricePerry. Your suggestion compiles fine but then at what point and how do I take advantage of the type parameter? In other words how can I rely on the type when the client calls the digest method?

Comment: You take advantage of the type parameter when you declare the field responseData in your class. It's purely static, and there is only one class for all possible parameters.

Comment: You mean by casting like so: `DigestResponseData responseData = (DigestResponseData) digestResponseEntity.getBody().getResponseData();`

Comment: Well, you wouldn't need the cast here

Comment: Where would it be then?

Comment: Nowhere. It's precisely the point of templates: avoid class casts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here :

```
return restTemplate.postForEntity("/digest", digestRequest, TokenServerResponse<DigestResponseData>.class);
```

If your method expects to have a class value as last argument, you can only provide a class for it. Providing a class with generic type is not possible.
Casting is unavoidable but if you change your `TokenServerResponse` class to use also inheritance.

```
public abstract class TokenServerResponse<T> {
    private String responseCode;
    private String responseMessage;
    private T responseData;

    public T getResponseData() {
        return responseData;
    }
}

public class TokenServerResponseDigestResponseData extends TokenServerResponse<DigestResponseData> {

}
```

Now you can use `TokenServerResponseDigestResponseData` class here :

```
return restTemplate.postForEntity("/digest", digestRequest, TokenServerResponseDigestResponseData.class);
```

And when you do :

```
TokenServerResponseDigestResponseData instance = ...
DigestResponseData data = instance.getResponseData();
```

you don't need any cast.

Of course this solution is interesting if you have not dozen of classes to make them inherited from the `TokenServerResponse` class and you would like to work with specific types in client code.
In your case, `DigestResponseData` is required to make your processing since your generic type doesn't rely on a specific type but on Object type, so you should cast at a time in this way : `TokenServerResponse` to `TokenServerResponse<DigestResponseData>`.
 With the proposed solution, it is not required any longer.